# Remove the first .5 of a second from Wav file

Tags: c#, audio, wav

How can I remove the first .5 of a second from Wav file?

Comment: Rather than code it yourself, I'd recommend looking for open source WAV handling libraries if you can find them.

Answer (score 5):

Here is [the format](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html). You need to open up the file, find the size of the header, then remove the required number of samples. You can find the number of bits per sample in the header. A 16-bit WAV file at a sampling rate of 44100 Hz would require you to remove `(16/8) * 44100 * 0.5 = 44100 bytes`

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search turned up a [library](http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx) that may be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it programatically, you need a wav file parser.  The general algorithm would be

```
A) open the file
b) find the fmt chunk
c) parse to calculate X =  bytes per sample * samples per second.
d) find the data chunk
e) remove the first X bytes
f) adjust the size of the data chunk
g) adjust the size of the initial RIFF chunk.
h) write the new file.
```